# Velocity Question & Acceleration

Tags: calculus, physics, derivatives

Below I have a question that I tried to solve on a exam. I am curious as to the actual way to approach the question. What I did was set the equation equal to $0$ and get $t = -3$ then I plugged in $3$ into the derivative of the equation and I got $128$ ft/sec. But apparently I approached it wrong. What is the right way to approach the question and solve it for the questions below?

> If a rock is thrown upward on Earth, with an initial velocity of 32
>   ft/sec from the  top of a 48 ft building, we can model the height of
>   the rock at time t  by     $s(t) = −16t^2+ 32t + 48$. After throwing
>   the rock up, it will at some point be  level again with the top of the
>   48 ft building.
>
> What will the velocity be at this time?
>
> Find the acceleration, why is it constant?

Comment: Need to set $-16t^2+32t+48=48$, because $48$ is the height when we pass the top of the building again. You can see (by putting $t=0$) that they are measuring distances from ground level.  Definitely you must not put $-16t^2+32t+48$ equal to $0$.

Comment: For the second, the acceleration is constant at -32 ft/sec^2.  To see this, take two derivatives of $s(t)$ and this is what you get.  This is an approximation, valid near the earth's surface, that gravity is the same strength at all places and directed downward.

Comment: So in order to answer the secondpart of the question what steps do i follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for **constant vertical acceleration only**, the position of the object is given by:

$$s\left(t\right) = s_0 + v_ot + \frac {1}{2} a t^2,$$

with constant vertical acceleration $a$, initial velocity and position $v_0$ and $s_0$, respectively, and current vertical position $s$.

Since our initial height and final height are both $48$ feet, we have:

$$48 = 48 + 32t - 16t^2 \tag{2}$$

Solving for the time to where the rock is at the same height it started at leads us to:

$$0= -16t^2 + 32t \implies t = 0, 2 \space \text{sec} \tag{3} $$

Obviously the rock is at the same height at $t = 0$, so at $t = 2$ sec is where it makes a parabola-like movement and comes back down to the original height of the $48$ foot building.

Taking the derivative of our position function, $s(t)$ and plugging in $t = 2$ sec leaves us:

$$s'(t) = -32t + 32 \implies v = -32 \space \text{feet/sec} \tag{4} $$

Taking the derivative again leads us to:

$$s''(t) = -32 \space \text{feet per second per second} \tag{5}$$

As expected, $s''(t)=a$ is indeed constant, since the ball is only accelerating due to gravity which is roughly $-32$ feet per second per second. Also, you could note that since acceleration is the second derivative of a position function and our position function was a quadratic, it follows that the acceleration function is constant since taking the derivative each time lowers the power. Further, as noted in equation (1), the formula **only** holds for **constant** acceleration, so it is a bit circular to see that since your given equation fits the model formula (1), the object undergoes constant acceleration.

Comment: You have obscured that between the first and second equations you redefined the origin without changing the variable.  I think it would be clearer to say that s(0)=48 as that is the height of the building and when it is again level with the top of the building you have s(t)=48.  You reach the same solution.

Comment: @Ross Yeah, I was a bit unclear. After a year of mechanics, you do these real quick, sorry. I edited the post in hopes of making it easier to understand.

Comment: So in order to answer the secondpart of the question what steps do i follow?

Comment: @soniccool What do you mean the "second part"? The question regarding acceleration/why is it constant?

Comment: @JoeL. The question is What will the velocity be at this time?
Find the acceleration, why is it constant? or is that the same thing that it is asking because i understand the velocity is -32ft/sec, but how do i go ahead to find the acceleration?

Comment: Well $s'(t)$ or rather $v(t) = -32t + 32$. So, taking the derivative of the velocity function gives us the acceleration function. $s''(t) = v'(t) = -32.$ So, the acceleration is always a constant $-32$ feet per second per second.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we actually don't need to know $t$. By symmetry, the velocity when the rock reaches the "throw" level again must be the negative of the throw velocity.

Since the throw velocity is $32$, the answer to the **first** question must be $-32$ (feet per second).

Comment: Or one could invoke conservation of energy.

Comment: I don't think he has gotten to energy yet. *Usually* kinematics is taught before energy.

Comment: So in order to answer the secondpart of the question what steps do i follow?

Answer (score 1):

When the rock is level again with the building, $s(t) = 48$.  So solving for time,

$-16t^2 + 32t = 0$ gives $t=0,2$.  So it appears that you just made a mistake in your calculation for $t$.  Your method for finishing the question seems correct, just using $t=2$ instead.